# Thread Safe mempool is not giving better performance compared to traditional new delete approach in C++ , Why?

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, memory-management, low-latency

I have implemented mempool , when it is not thread safe in that case it is giving be better result almost 1/3rd of traditional new,delete but as soon as I make it thread safe it is performing slower compare to traditional new,delete.

Mempool.cpp

```
    template<typename T>
class Mempool {
private:

    std::atomic<int> totalSize;
//  int totalSize; // without thread safe
    T **head;
//  int allocPos; // without thread safe
    std::atomic<int> allocPos;
    void initialize() {

        head = (T **) calloc(totalSize, sizeof(T *));
        for (int i = allocPos; i < totalSize; i++) {
            head[i] = (T*) calloc(1, sizeof(T));
        }
    }

    void expand() {
        totalSize += totalSize;
        head = (T**) realloc(head, sizeof(T*) * totalSize);
        for (int i = allocPos; i < totalSize; i++) { // As data till allocPos is already allocated
            head[i] = (T*) calloc(1, sizeof(T));
        }
    }
public:
    Mempool(int size) :
            totalSize(size), head(nullptr), allocPos(0) {
        initialize();
    }
    T* alloc() {
        if (allocPos >= totalSize)
            expand();
        T* temp = head[allocPos++];
        return temp;
    }
    void dealloc(T *f_node) {
        head[--allocPos] = f_node;
    }
    ~Mempool() {
        for (int i = allocPos; i < totalSize; i++) { // As data till allocPos is already allocated
            free(head[i]);
        }
        free(head);
    }
};

class Variable {
public:
    int a;
    int b;
    long c;
    int d;
    int e;
    long f;
    double g;
        char h;
    };

Mempool<Variable> varpool(200);
int main() {
    const int testSize = 200;
    std::string c("Case1");
    Timer t1(c);
    t1.start();
    Variable *var1[testSize];
    for (int j = 0; j < 30; ++j) {
        for (int i = 0; i < testSize; ++i)
            var1[i] = varpool.alloc();
        for (int i = 0; i < testSize; ++i)
            varpool.dealloc(var1[i]);
    }
    t1.stop();
    c = "Case2";
    Timer t2(c);
    t2.start();
    Variable *var2[testSize];
    for (int j = 0; j < 30; ++j) {
        for (int i = 0; i < testSize; ++i)
            var2[i] = new Variable();
        for (int i = 0; i < testSize; ++i)
            delete var2[i];
    }

    t2.stop();
    return 0;
}
```

Here timer showing more time for case1 during thread safe implementation. I'm assuming it should be less, please provide what changes should I made in my implementation to achieve that.

OS:Linux Centos 7, 64bit 4core.

Comment: "Thread safety" means synchronization and contention points between the threads. And on a modern multi-core CPU it could also mean cache-synchronization between the in-core caches.

Comment: On another note, I hope the code you show is not a copy-paste of your actual code, as it contains some horrible flaws. First it can't be used with any kind of type which requires construction (like a class with a default constructor), as you don't do any construction calls. Secondly, you don't have any error checking. And thirdly (and related to the previous point), never assign back to the pointer you pass to `realloc`, as if `realloc` returns a null pointer you lose the original and still valid original pointer.

Comment: It isn't threadsafe, because you have unprotected accesses to `head`, or two threads calling into `expand` simultaneously.

Comment: thanks @1201ProgramAlarm for pointing that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude agree with you it has lots of flaws but I'm currently more interested in performance.

Comment: Perhaps sharing the same mempool across threads, making synchronization for every operation on the pool necessary isn't the most effective approach? Also, making the size variables atomic doesn't make the mempool thread safe. You should probably use one mutex and lock_guards instead of atomics.

Comment: One possible way to gain performance would be to give each thread its own separate Mempool, then no synchronization would be necessary (downside would be that you couldn't allocate an object in one thread and free it in another; whether that would be a problem depends on your program's design)